# rake aborted! Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have been trying to fix the error but always keep getting Rake aborted!

```
Load Error: cannot load such file -- minitest/reporters
```

Get same error while running the following command:

```
bundle exec rake test
```

I am a new bee here, so many thanks for your help.

```
changeme-mac-2:sample_app1 tshrestha$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.7
changeme-mac-2:sample_app1 tshrestha$ rake test
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- minitest/reporters
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/tshrestha/Desktop/workspace/sample_app1/test/test_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/tshrestha/Desktop/workspace/sample_app1/test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/tshrestha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run => test:units
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
changeme-mac-2:sample_app1 tshrestha$ bundler -v
Bundler version 1.7.6
changeme-mac-2:sample_app1 tshrestha$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin14.0]"
```

Here is my Gemfile with the following gems.

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'
gem "minitest", '5.4.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# gem 'unicorn'
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: Run `gem install minitest` and try again

Comment: tried and still throws the same error.

Comment: where did you load the minutest/reporters files ? Or is it a typo/spelling mistake?

Comment: sorry it is a typo. should be 'LoadError: cannot load such file -- minitest/reporters'

Comment: you don't need minitest in your Gemfile, remove it and try again.

Comment: @Anthony tried it, still same error.

Comment: I can not test it either... same error is coming up. Any help will be great thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`minitest-reporters` is a separate gem from Minitest. You should add the following to your Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
end
```

Re-run bundle, and it should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you finally I can finally test now. It is a great help.